# How to prevent html div from expanding when text size is changed

Tags: html, css

So, I have a navigation bar.  I want each link text to grow and bold when on hover.  I have achieved this using css, but now whenever teh mouse hovers over the link the text size grows,b ut so does the div to accomodate that text. Any ideas on how to fix this.  Here is the jsfiddle link:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5pJk/)

CODE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div id = "navigation">
        <ul id = "nav">
            <li><a href = "mechadogs.org/home" class = "navlink">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "mechadogs.org/team" class = "navlink">Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a href = "mechadogs.org/gallery" class = "navlink">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href = "mechadogs.org/community" class = "navlink">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href = "mechadogs.org/first" class = "navlink">FIRST</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

#navigation{
    background-color:black;
    width:98%;
    font-family:calibri;
    padding:1%;
    margin-left:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
}
#nav{
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul#nav li{
    float:left;
    padding:0 6%;
}
.navlink{
    display:block;
    background-color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
.navlink:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14pt; 
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**To fix the horizontal pushing:**
Instead of using `padding` to space the items apart, one solution is to use `width` and `text-align: center;` so that the items don't push the other items after them.

**To fix the vertical pushing:**
One solution is to specify a `line-height` equal to the largest `font-size` (which would be your `:hover` size)

```css
#navigation{
    background-color:black;
    width:98%;
    font-family:calibri;
    padding:1%;
    margin-left:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
}
#nav{
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul#nav li{
    float:left;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
}
.navlink{
    display:block;
    background-color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    line-height:14pt;
}
.navlink:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14pt; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id = "navigation">
        <ul id = "nav">
            <li><a href = "mechadogs.org/home" class = "navlink">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "mechadogs.org/team" class = "navlink">Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a href = "mechadogs.org/gallery" class = "navlink">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href = "mechadogs.org/community" class = "navlink">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href = "mechadogs.org/first" class = "navlink">FIRST</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't even going to bother with the horizontal pushing.

Comment: No problem! If you found one of our answers to be the solution, make sure to mark it as such when you get the chance. Good luck with your website!

Comment: This answer saved me so much time! Simple and perfect

Answer (score 2):

Add a `max-height: 30px;` to `#navigation`.

In general, if you are looking for something that transform shape/size aesthetically, it's easier to work with min/max width in pixels, rather then %.